# ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' error for new flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, android-sdk-tools

I have installed flutter by following all the steps. When I create a new project in Visual studio I can run it on Chrome. However, when I try to run it on an android device I keep getting ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' error.

Here is the output:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
Process 'command 'F:\f\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741795

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 48s Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
```

I tried running `.\gradlew clean  build` in the android folder. And here is the output:

```
> Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'F:\f\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741795

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
7 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 5 up-to-date
```

Here is the output for flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4046], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.19.3 on channel stable at F:\f
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ba39319843 (8 days ago), 2024-03-07 15:22:21 -0600
    • Engine revision 2e4ba9c6fb
    • Dart version 3.3.1
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at F:\androidsdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: F:\Android\android studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at F:\Android\android studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)

[√] VS Code (version 1.87.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.84.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • moto g32 (mobile) • 192.168.29.6:37385 • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows            • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4046]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome             • web-javascript • Google Chrome 122.0.6261.129
    • Edge (web)        • edge               • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 122.0.2365.92

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```